# creating SQLite database using R with read.csv.sql

Tags: r, sqlite, sqldf

I have been trying to create an SQLite database using R with read.csv.sql. I can manage standard datasets such as mtcars and iris however, I cannot do so with my dataset. The following is what one line of the csv looks like:

```
"{BBB}","89000","2002-05-10 00:00","A","A","A","A","A","","A"
```

So there is a reference, a number, a date and a few columns with text, and some empty cells (I have taken out a few cells just so that it fits on the screen).

**The following is an example of one code I tried but I am always getting the following type of error:**

Any ideas what I should be doing intstead.
I am thinking perhaps eol or field.types. 
All my tests fail.

> RS_sqlite_import: test.csv line 4 expected 16 columns of data but
>   found 17.

I have seen a lot of people with this error but I cannot get a solution.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("attach testingdb as new")

read.csv.sql("Test.csv", 
             sql = "CREATE TABLE main AS SELECT * from file",
             header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep = ",",
             dbname = "testingdb")
```

Comment: I think you should pay attention to what the error message is saying.  Can you post the first 2-3 lines of one of these CSV files?

Comment: "{AAA1}","1","2002-05-10 00:00","A","A","A","A","A","","A","","A","A","A","A","A"
"{AAA2}","1","2002-11-01 00:00","A","A","A","A","A","","A","","A","A","A","A","A"
"{AAA3}","1","2002-05-30 00:00","A","A","A","A","A","","A","A","A","A","A","A","A"

Comment: a smaller version of the file imports fine if you load the whole file, but the idea of going through this avenue is to avoid this because the actual data far exceeds what I have in memory.

Comment: So what's the root cause here?  A lack of memory, or a formatting problem with one or more lines in your source file?

Comment: i think I need to insert more arguments into read.csv.sql because it is expecting the wrong number of columns. In the code above, it is relying on default settings.... but I cannot work it out. I have not done this before. I would say the source file must be fine.

Comment: When I said the smaller file works if you load it into memory, i meant if you load it in as: f<-read.csv("Test.csv")#  And then use f as the first argument in read.csv.sql, intead of the csv, it works. But I cannot do this on the actual file because the actual file exceeds my memory size.